# Visual studio Code Chrome Debugging extension opens a new Chrome page instead of debugging in VSC GUI

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't seem to make it work. I also tried to add /myDirectory after {workspaceFolder}. It opens a chrome page to the unreachable localhost
Here is my launch.json config :

```
   "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "debug in Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why is localhost unreachable? Or is it "just" because of the port 3000? You should alter the "url" part to you reachable site like you would call you web app in the browser, like `http://localhost/mywebapp`. It is the correct behaviour that a new chrome instance is opened. You can still debug JavaScript code in VSC then.

Comment: Well, I tried port 8080 and modifing the url to no avail. Also, according to this tut it should not be necessary to change the url as long as you are in the right webroot. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AX7uybwukkk   12:35min

Comment: Hm, ok. But what exactly is the url you would type into your browser to access your webapp? Does your webserver run on port 8080? My launch config looks exactly like yours, just I altered the url to my "real" url. Another thought: Maybe it could also be a firewall problem!?

Answer (score 0):

In VSC "Open with the live server" as one would do normally [Alt+L Alt+O] and look at the url it opened in the browser. That included the IP address, port # and filename. Cut and paste that into the launch.json config url section.